# Значок приложения в Delphi.

Tags: delphi, exe, delphi-7, icon

Вот сделал я программу. Перед этим поменял значок в свойстве Icon. Но после компиляции и образования exe-файла всё равно значок не изменился! Что делать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вы поменяли значок главной формы (свойство `TForm.Icon`).

Чтобы поменять значок exe-файла, т.е. проекта, надо это сделать в `Project/Options/Application/Icon` в главном меню.

Answer (score 2):

А значок надо поменять в настройках.
К сожалению, Delphi под рукой сейчас не имею, но помню, что где-то в верхней панели, в настройках есть опция поменять значок.
Поищите внимательно)

Comment: Да, нашёл в options -> application, благодарю.